Build failed - Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 + flutter
I am using jvmTarget as 1.8 in build.gradle
android {


    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    namespace "com.app.example
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    java {
        toolchain {
            languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)  // or 21 depending on your choice
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant -> renameArtifact(variant, defaultConfig) }
}

But still I am getting the error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':photo_manager:compileDebugKotlin'.


Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

I checked all the answers available online but nothing is helpful. Can anyone help me with this.
